# The specified blob does not exist - Shows in azure browser - but when I click download does not exist

Tags: azure, blob

I've uploaded some blobs to `azure`.
They show in the browser when I log in, but when I attempt to download them I get following message:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>BlobNotFound</Code>
<Message>
The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:d3cd1a18-1e48-47bd-9985-4ab7e655eed2 Time:2013-09-19T15:02:16.4158548Z
</Message>
</Error>
```

Screenshot browsing (showing the blobs)[image]

Screenshot showing what happens after I click download
[image]

Comment: Please ensure that the blob container does not have "Private" ACL. In order for a blob to be accessed directly via browser, the container's ACL should be "Blob" or "Public". HTH.

Comment: I dont think that is it.  I have 2 containers private, and 1 public and i can download from the browser with all 3.  What happens when you use something like [CloudXplorer](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer)? Does the file show up there?

Comment: @paqogomez I seriously doubt that. Only way you could download a blob from a private blob container directly through a browser is by using a Shared Access Signature URL.

Comment: Well, I am.  Still, the `blob not found` error doesn't seem indicative of a permission issue.

Comment: Trying to access a private blob directly will result in a 404 unless a valid SAS is added to the URI.

Comment: I can access other private blobs when logged in via the azure portal, so I'm sure that is not it.

Comment: Looking at the 2nd screenshot, the portal actually creates a SAS URL and that's why you're able to access the private blobs. Will it be possible for you to post the actual URL which is giving you error here?

Comment: What is the danger of me posting the actual URL, does it only give people access to that one blob? e.g. it doesn't compromise my whole container?

Comment: No, it won't compromise the entire container. Just that blob for which you will share the URL. Once we have identified the cause, you could just delete that blob.

Comment: Here is the link I get when I click download: http://biztechsoftware.blob.core.windows.net/arklesecuritytf/Tommy%2520French%2520Toals.North%2520Street.1250251?sv=2012-02-12&st=2013-09-20T08%3A51%3A20Z&se=2013-09-20T08%3A58%3A20Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=mhJazHmbKXwQp1cpIyFho5B5ag8aPF6TPYpiig9y8uo%3D

Comment: http://biztechsoftware.blob.core.windows.net/arklesecuritytf/Tommy%20French%20Toals.North%20Street.1250251 with the http:// this time.

Answer (score 8):

I think I know why you're running into this issue. I believe its an issue with the portal. If you notice, the name of your blob is: `Tommy French Toals.North Street.1250251` and it contains spaces. However if you look at the URL the name is coming as: `Tommy%2520French%2520Toals.North%2520Street.1250251`. Notice the presence of `%2520`. What portal software is doing is that it is performing URL encoding twice - first, it URL encodes `space` in the blob name to `%20` and then again URL encodes the `%` sign to `%25` and this is messing things up for you.

Just to be double sure, I uploaded a file which contains spaces in its name in my storage account and when I try to download the blob through the portal, it failed with the same error as yours. Then I created a SAS URI for the same blob using storage client library, and it worked perfectly fine. Here's the code I used for creating SAS URI:

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("myaccount", "myaccountkey"), true);
        var blobContainer = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
        var blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("this file has spaces in its name.txt");
        var sas = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
        });
        var sasUrl = blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sas;
```

Try downloading a file which does not contain spaces or any special characters in its name and it should work just fine.

Comment: How do I fix this for files that do contain the spaces though, as I need to access these previously uploaded blobs?

Comment: As I said above, the SAS URL created via code above works so what you could do is write some code to create SAS URI on these files and download the blobs using those SAS URIs.

Comment: Yet another alternative could be to download these blobs from various desktop tools (including Visual Studio). One such free tool is Azure Explorer from Cerebrata (http://www.cerebrata.com/labs/azure-explorer). HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri is there any whay to achieve the same in JAVA? I am doing `url = blob.getUri() +"?"+ blob.generateSharedAccessSignature(getPolicy(), null);` and getting issues in the same sceanrio like file name containing spaces

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work by:

- Opening the Azure Storage App and navigating to the container / blob
- Right-click the blob and selecting "Properties..."
- Copy/paste the text after the server path from the URL

For example, if the URL shows as: `https://<storageaccount>.windows.net/somecontainer/someblob`

The text to copy/paste would be: `somecontainer/someblob`

Answer (score 0):

Go and Edit container meta data on azure bolb storage. change access private to public.
[Azure blob storage container edit page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0veFv.jpg)

Comment: I think this is the answer

Comment: It's only the answer if you want all of the contents of your blob viewable to the world.

Answer (score 0):

check file name, its case sensitive. after correcting case it started working for me.